# Classical particle in box - Force on wall

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

I'm trying to calculate the force exerted on the wall by a particle contained in a 1 dimensional box of length $L$ using classical physics.

The hint is that the change in momentum is given by

$$\int dtF$$

and to use the average over time.

---

This is what I've tried

$$F=\frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t}$$

with

$$\Delta p=p_{after}-p_{before}$$
$$\Delta p=-2mv$$

and 
$$\Delta t=\frac{\Delta l}{v} $$
$$\Delta t=\frac{L}{v}.$$

Combining expressions gives

$$F=-\frac{2mv^2}{L}=-\frac{4}{L}\frac{mv^2}{2}=-\frac{4}{L}E$$

---

The answer is supposed to be $$F=\frac{2E}{L}$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Average force and pressure in a 3D box due to quantum non-interacting particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67753/)

Comment: The expression $\Delta t=\frac{\Delta l}{\Delta v}$ is wrong. It should be $\Delta t = \frac{\Delta l}{v}$.

Comment: Right, that makes sense thanks! Im getting closer to the correct solution. I'm assuming there is something wrong with my $$\Delta l=L $$ expression. I thought at the beginning of time the particle is in the middle of the box and at the end of time it is back in the middle again so that it has traveled a length of L.

Comment: What is $\Delta l$?  Or am I just blind?  Just saw your comment.  You are correct, $\Delta l \neq L$.  Think about what $\Delta l$ should actually be.  Think about the collision itself.

Comment: The distance traveled, sorry I should've specified that. And called it $$\Delta d$$

Comment: What distance traveled?   From one end of the box to the other?  Think:  should that distance have a bearing on the time duration of the collision?  I just saw your *latest* comment.  Please be extremely explicit in defining your terms.   What is $\Delta d$?

Comment: Well I assumed I can think if the particle traveling from the middle of the box L/2 units to the left, hitting the wall, then travelling L/2 units to the right. This might be where I'm making a mistake..

Comment: Yes, that's a mistake.  Think about what $\Delta t$ really is, and what you would need in order to find it.  Again, don't be lulled into sloppy definitions.  What *exactly* is $\Delta t$?

Comment: Okey so
$$\Delta t$$
must be the time it takes to change the momentum of the particle which is the same as the time of the collision. Then
$$\Delta l$$
is the distance is takes to change the momentum. But I cant understand how to find this distance.. It feels like the distance it takes to change the momentum ideally is infinitely small. . I'm trying but I'm really bad at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost have it. At least if what you actually are trying to calculate is not the instantaneous force (which anyway can't be obtained with the information provided), but the *average force*.

You're calculating the force on one of the walls, right? Well, that means the time between collisions of the particle with this wall is not

$$ \Delta t = \frac{L}{v}, $$

but

$$ \Delta t = \frac{2L}{v}, $$

because the particle must go to the other wall and back, thus covering the length $L$ of the box not once, but twice.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to solve the question completely, but I will give you idea on how to solve it. If you still get stuck, then comment down below.

Since it is not mentioned, I am going to assume the collision of the particle with the wall to be elastic.

Now think what will be the change if momentum of the particle after collision with the wall, if it is travelling with a velocity $v$. You know the length and velocity. So you can find $\Delta t$. Now you have $\Delta p$ and $\Delta t$. You can get the force $F$. If you want the expression of force to be in terms of energy, then figure out how kinetic energy term is concealed in the current expression of force.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was a good hint. I updated my attempt at solution. Unfortunately I didn't get it quite right so if you can give me one more hint at what I'm doing wrong that would be much appreciated.